# MPI mpdboot error

Tags: boot, cluster, mpi

I have a problem with MPI in a 3-box cluster with machines named `head`, `node1` and `node2` respectively. I install a newer version on `node2` and the problems arises. When I include only `head` and `node2` in the MPI ring, and try to boot with `mpdboot` from `head`, I get the error:

```
mpdboot_head (handle_mpd_output 399): from mpd on node2, invalid port info:
mpd_port=55270
```

When I try to boot from `node2`, I get the error:

```
mpdboot_node2 (handle_mpd_output 426): from mpd on head, invalid port info:
no_port
```

However, if I boot MPI with `mpd` manually on `head` and then add `node2` into the MPI ring, no errors are issued.

What's more, `mpd` can be boot without any error on `head` and `node1` only. Is this some problems related to downward compatibility?

How could I solve this?